# вывод image из Базы Данных на экран

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM table WHERE ...");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Теперь в $row[0] - бинарный файл png. Как вывести его на экран?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В самом простом случае:

```
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
echo $row[0];
```

Ну а про нецелесообразность хранения даже маленьких картинок в БД уже сказали в другом вопросе.

Comment: Хорошо, не буду хранить. Но вернемся к вопросу. header это понятно, но у меня до картинки уже миллион выводов на экран, заголовком не получится

Comment: А с другими заголовками и не получится вообще. HTML должен выводиться отдельно, а картинка - ссылкой в этом HTML, на скрипт, который только одну картинку и отдаст. Как-то так:

    <img src="/index.php?action=get_avatar&id=1234" .../>

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе это известно. Получается, в Базе данных ВООБЩЕ нет смысла хранить изображение и пр.бинарные файлы. Разве что только чтобы отослать их клиенту по запросу...